# select element with changing xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooAlW.png)

say I wanted to select the element with class=kbkey button red_selected sel. Its xpath from the example in the pic would be //*[@id="virtualKeysWrapper"]/div[3], so I have the following code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="virtualKeysWrapper"]/div[3]'))).click()
```

However, the div position of this element would change everytime I refresh the site. Was wondering what should I do to successfully select the element with class=kbkey button red_selected sel successfully everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using index position in XPath if at all possible for this very reason. Without knowing exactly what the rest of the DOM looks like, my best guess is that you could use the following expression:

```
//div[@id='virtualKeysWrapper']/div[@class='kbkey button red_selected sel']
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
//div[@id='virtualKeysWrapper']/div[@sel='true']
```

Comment: i found another solution:
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="kbkey button red_selected sel"]'))).click() 

would this be any bad?

Comment: @hbae is not bad unless there other parts of the DOM containing the same class; in which case the first instance is selected and that might not be the one you will need. Having the parent component in the XPath might be a better choice. Again, it all depends. The shorter the relative path, the better it is. But that is not always possible.